# NativeScript - How to prevent CSS minification?

Tags: javascript, css, build, nativescript, minify

I've got NativeScript 3.3.0 installed. My project-wide CSS is in `app/app.css`.

When I run the app, either by console

`tns run android --device [device-ID of my preferred emulator]`

or by starting it in an Android emulator through JetBrain's WebStorm (with NativeScript plugin installed), the `app.css` always gets minified during the rebuilding process after I do some changes to it while the app is running.

Is it somehow possibile to prevent NativeScript from minifying the CSS file upon building the app? I wished there was a run parameter with which I could toggle that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have nativescript-dev-sass installed
if you uninstall it, the minification should stop.

But ideally, you would want to keep the minification.

Edit:

you can do, 
`npm remove -D nativescript-dev-sass`

and you remove those nativescript-dev-sass files which are in hooks folder (if it doesn't get removed automatically).

Also if you see `node-sass` in your devDependencies, remove that as well with

`npm remove -D node-sass` and you should be good to go. Cheers!

Comment: I ran `tns plugin remove nativescript-dev-sass` in the console. I got _Plugin "nativescript-dev-sass" is not installed._ Yet, I've got some scss files in my project which were generated when creating the project.

Comment: Might this be a part of the `nativescript-dev-webpack`?

Comment: can you check the hooks folder once? there could be some dev-sass remnants there

Comment: also to be on safer side, check your devDependencies in package.json, see if there is nativescript-dev-sass, because it is not like other plugins of nativescript.

Comment: Indeed there are four `nativescript-dev-sass.js` files, on in each folder. And the package.json also has an entry `"nativescript-dev-sass": "1.3.2"`.

Comment: So my suspicion was right. Now you do, `npm remove -D nativescript-dev-sass` and you remove those dev-sass files which are in hooks folder. Also if you see `node-sass` in your devDependencies, remove that as well with `npm remove -D node-sass` and you should be good to go. Cheers!

Comment: Looks like the "trick" is to delete the four mentioned js files (not the coolest way). But I may not remove the `nativescript-dev-sass` from the package.json. Otherwise, the project won't build. Anyway, thanks for the help and patience! Feel free to add this to your answer, so I can mark it as the solution ... for now. ;-)